# A class is looking for methods of another class in the maven repository instead of the source code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, repository, m2eclipse

I have two (really more, but we are interested in these two now) projects in the Eclipse workspace. One of them has got a class A that just obtained several new static methods.

I want another one class B, in another project, to call these methods. But I see these methods underlined by red, with message `"The method ... is undefined for the type A"`. If I go into "open implementation" for the class A, Eclipse tries to open the source code attached to the old jar that lies in the maven repository. No source is attached, so I see only the tab with the name of the A class (it is there), but that is the old class version, without new methods.

Clean, Maven Clean - don't help. The same with restart Eclipse, clean all projects, reopening projects.

Please, don't propose to reinstall Eclipse - what I have is the picture JUST after reinstalling of everything, updating the project, maven installing it (worked), and adding these functions.

A Maven Install does not work for the same reason  - falling on these references to new methods.

If I clean the repository by hand - on Maven Clean I am getting a FATAL error, with a demand for that old jar.

I have put the reference to the correct source of the A class to the Maven task source. I have added the reference to the correct project of the A class to the project of the B class in the Eclipse Properties of the project. Nothing changed.

There are similar problems here on SO, but I managed to get the some multiplication of all of them: both Eclipse and Maven had gone mad, no added references help, no cleaning helps.

Edit.
I have tried to make maven to create new snapshots, but the result is absolutely the same picture... "cannot find symbol" that is in the source! What is interesting, after removing of the repository the Eclipse starts to see the symbols OK. But I must run maven and it won't run with removed repository. Just as a crazy idea: Is there some maven tool to clean the repository so that it will know there is nothing there and won't try to look for things in it?

Comment: After you change the code in a project you should run mvn install to put the new jar into your local repo (assuming you're using SNAPSHOT in the version name)

Comment: Yes. But instead it uses the old version of jar, without changing it.

Comment: Just now I have got advice to remove not only the project part of repository, but the whole com folder in it. Trying...

Comment: Have you configured in Eclipse to force an update (SNAPSHOT/releases) usage (mvn -U equivalent on command line)...

Comment: "com" removement won't help, too.

Comment: @khmarbaise That sounds good. And where can I set that in Eclipse?

Comment: @khmarbaise I think, I had found that myself. Now trying...

Comment: Absolutely the same picture... "cannot find symbol" that is in the source! What is interesting, after removing of the repository the Eclipse starts to see the symbols OK. But I must run maven and it won't run with removed repository. Is there some maven tool to clean the repository so that it will know there is nothing there and won't try to look for things in it?

Answer (score 0):

I have met with three unpleasant situations combined:

1. The local maven repository was damaged
2. The jar written in it was deprecated.
3. Due to some committing to local CVS branch and pulling and checkout from the common CVS repository it happened that parent snapshot referenced to by some poms and the main snapshot declared in the root pom had different versions.

### Solution

The first problem can not be normally corrected using the plugin maven only. You have to install the standalone maven, add its bin to PATH, an launch in folder of your root pom (exit the Eclipse at first and stop jar that you are repairing, if you have it running):

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false
```

Then, if you want to work in standalone maven, you should put the correct settings into youruserroot/.m2 folder.

After that,

```
mvn -U -X -e install
```

That will fail on every local pom with incorrect parent Snapshot. Go into every local lesser poms and correct the references. Repeat, until it stops to fail on snapshots.

I had found advice to run

```
mvn -U -X -e clean install -DskipTests=true
```

for installing all, but without test running. (I had repaired an error in the line, so don't try to google for it). But you can already use the plugin Maven at this stage, too.

So, you run Maven clean and Maven Install in the plugin... And hurra! - the classes see other classes as they are in the source code and not in some old jar, and that works in both maven and Eclipse.